# Why hasn't Cersei tried to make peace with Jon Snow?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

As Queen in Season 7, Cersei has yet to reach out to the North to try and mend the broken peace between the North and King's Landing.  If she did and they came to some sort of agreement, it would reduce a potential ally for Danny and a potential threat for her, allowing her to focus on more important parts of the map and turn her gaze upon them later.

What are Cersei's motivating reasons to not reach out to Jon?

Comment: I don't think she would be able, and I'm not sure she wants to. Lannisters were responsible for the death and misfortune of many of his familiars.

Comment: You know she's *bat sh-t crazy*...right?

Comment: Cersei doesn't play well with others.  Tyrion makes the point that she is a terrible ruler, but her viciousness, drive and utter ruthlessness make her quite effective at taking out rivals.

Comment: Watch seasons 1-6...?  I mean, its quite clear....

Comment: "Sorry about your dad... and your brother... and, as far as we know, your sister.  But I'm sure THIS Stark-Lannister alliance will work out!  Oh, and your other brother."

Comment: @DanStaley - technically, that was all on house Baratheon.

Comment: @Davor You mean Tywin *Lannister* didn't mastermind the Red Wedding, and Jaime *Lannister* didn't father Joffrey?

Comment: @JDoe - Joffrey is a legitimate and recognised Baratheon and all those things happened under his rule.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

She *did* try... in S7E1 Jon [receives](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/read-cerseis-dragonstone-summons-to-jon-snow) a raven from Kings Landing.

> Cersei of the House Lannister, First of Her Name, Queen of the Andals and the First Men, Protector of the Seven Kingdoms, summons the rebel and bastard Jon Snow to Kings Landing, to bend the knee to his rightful Queen or suffer the fate of all traitors.

Granted this is not a very effective way to make peace, and given Cersei's past history nothing says she will honor it! However, even for a "Mad Queen" an uneasy peace is better than open rebellion, but given the recent history between the two houses I am sure both sides realize no peace terms could be made.

[image: cersei's letter]

Comment: Calling someone a rebel and a bastard is not a good idea if you want to negotiate at least an armistice with them, imho...

Comment: @arc_lupus the question is about trying. Nothing about the potential effectiveness of such attempts. ;)

Comment: @arc_lupus What's your point? Criticizing mad queens renowned for their viciousness is also not a good idea.

Comment: Wasn't it Danny's raven to Jon summoning him to bend the knee?